# Create and change game State in runtime

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm struggling with issue mentioned in the title.For now I'm setting default one in constructor and then i want to change it with my function, however it doesn't seem to work.

```
 void AMyGameModeBase::SwapGameState(AGameStateBase* GameStateVariable)
    {
        GameStateClass = GameStateVariable->StaticClass();
    }
```

How can I do this properly? Good explanation would be awesome :)

EDIT:

So this is my whole code:
MyGameModeBase.h

```
#pragma once

#include "GameFramework/GameMode.h"
#include "MyGameModeBase.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class PROJECT_API AMyGameModeBase : public AGameMode
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:

    AMyGameModeBase();

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category="GameState")
    void SwapGameState(AGameStateBase* GameStateVariable);
};
```

MyGameModeBase.cpp

```
#include "Project.h"
#include "MyGameModeBase.h"


AMyGameModeBase::AMyGameModeBase()
{
    GameStateClass = AGameStateBase::StaticClass();
}


void AMyGameModeBase::SwapGameState(AGameStateBase* GameStateVariable)
{
    GameStateClass = GameStateVariable->StaticClass();
}
```

What I'm doing then is:
1.Open GameMode blueprint
2.Drag from Event begin play and call SwapGameState
3.I'm creating variable that is reference to MyGameState.
4.Then I'm printing with print string name that i get with node "GetGameState" and see that it's not changed.

What i want to achieve is:
1.CreateGameState in runtime
2.Set it to used default game state also in runtime.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is your exact issue? What are the definitions of all these types and declarations of these variables and functions? Please provide a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain your situation more thoroughly.

Comment: I've edited my question. There is no error it's just not working.

Comment: GameState is intended for communicating information from a server to any connected clients. Why are you trying to set GameState to something else?

Comment: I'm swapping them for other platforms. They have some colliding functionality so I've chosen to have more than one and I need to swap them depending on platform ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The StaticClass function is a static function that you call like this `MyStateClass::StaticClass()`

What you want is this

```
void AMyGameModeBase::SwapGameState(AGameStateBase* GameStateVariable)
{
    GameStateClass = GameStateVariable->GetClass();
}
```

Comment: For some reason after implementing this i get Access violation error:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFEBE7D2CDF (UE4Editor-Project.dll) in UE4Editor.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000010. occurred

Comment: The variable you pass is probably null, if you want more help you have to show more code

Comment: There is no more code. Only passing in GameState reference. So I guess that's the case

Comment: What value are you passing to swap game state? In your repo step you don't seem to be connecting anything to the parameter pin

Comment: Pretty much any time you dereference a pointer, you'll want to be certain first that the pointer points to valid memory. In the case of the example above, GameStateClass = GameStateVariable ? GameStateVariable->GetClass() : nullptr; would be safer. If GameStateVariable points to a valid object, GameStateClass will be set to the value returned by GetClass(), but if it doesn't, GameStateClass will be set to nullptr.